# Docx content replacement

Tags: c#, replace, openxml, docx

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = 
       WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
{
    string docText = null;
    using (StreamReader sr = 
           new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
    {
        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    Regex regexText = new Regex("@@username@@");
    docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "john thomas ");

    using (StreamWriter sw = 
           new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
    {
        sw.Write(docText);
    }
}
```

This should replace matches on doctext by the name in the code. I checked the doctext and the word to replace (`@@username@@`) is split. There is sometimes XML contents between the 
`@@` and `username@@`. Sometimes the word itself is malformed.

How do I replace `@@username@@`?

Comment: Why are you not using the word processing merge features to provide fields with content instead of misusing regex?

Comment: Being no DOCX file format expert, I really doubt that you could operate with string functions on the content of a DOCX file. I suggest using Aspose.Words or [Spire](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/word-for-net-introduce.html).

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to have the tag in a textbox or table (maybe even with a prespecified id). I am not sure whether you have other tables or textboxes in the document, but grabbing whats inside the table or the textbox inside the only one in the document is really easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have code inside a Paragraph object, then you could do something like this (a poor Order n^2 solution ....) :

```
foreach (Paragraph para in wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Paragraph>()) 
{
    foreach(Run r in para.Elements<Run>()) 
    {
          if (r.Elements<text>().ElementAt(0).Text.Equals(string_to_search)) 
              r.Elements<Text>().ElementAt(0).Text = string_to_insert;
    }
}
```

Also, check out MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478255.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the Regex.  (This will include all the XML, but it will be replaced)

```
New Regex("@@.*?username.*?@@")
```

The ops code is the solution documented on MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb508261.aspx

If you multiple fields to replace with different names you may try calling this function between your reader and writer:

```
    Private Function ReplaceMatches(ByVal text As String) As String
        Dim Matches = Regex.Matches(text, "@@.*?@@")
        For Each m As Match In Matches
            For Each c As Capture In m.Captures
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Value) Then
                    text = text.Replace(c.Value, "NEW-VALUE")
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Return text
    End Function
```